# return the updated value after running the update query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Im sorry if the question seems odd and stupid but I need to know if it is possible or what.

So
I have the following query that updates the status of a request record in the requests table.

```
$updateQ = "UPDATE requests SET status = status+1 WHERE rid = '$rid'";
if($this->db->query($updateQ))
    return $this->db->select('status')->from('requests')->where('rid', $rid)->get()->row('status');
```

I wonder if I can get the value of the updated **status** field right after executing the query without running another select query.

Comment: no you cannot get it, after the update, the only thing that you can get are the affected rows, which is `1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. And I don't see, why you worry about it. I'd guess, that `rid` is your primary key. The `SELECT` afterwards should therefore be so fast, that you'll hardly notice it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use SELECT FOR UPDATE(for mySQL) or something similar to achieve atomicity in updating and selecting the last value.

```
SELECT counter_field FROM child_codes FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;
```

or use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` if you wish to get last inserted id for your update.

```
UPDATE counters
SET value = LAST_INSERT_ID(value) + 1
WHERE id = 1;
```

And then

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Read thru [select-update-single-statement-race-condition](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/select-update-single-statement-race-condition)

Thanks,
K

Comment: This is good information **in general**, but not really necessary in this case. Anyway, upvote.