# Return row after UPDATE in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-update

How to return an entire row or part of it after  UPDATE, INSERT .

Here is my query.

```
 UPDATE news SET title = 'changed' WHERE ID = 8 RETURNING *
```

It returns syntax error.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `'RETURNING *'` at line 1

I want to get the affected row data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MariaDB and MySQL in general does not have support for a `RETURNING` clause after an `UPDATE` statement.

You have to return the updated row in a separate statement directly after the `UPDATE` statement like this:

```
UPDATE news SET title = 'changed' WHERE ID = 8;
SELECT * FROM news WHERE ID = 8;
```

Or using the `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, if you're doing an `INSERT`, which is based on your connection (though, `RETURNING` is allowed for `INSERT` in MariaDB - see below).

```
INSERT INTO news (ID, title) VALUES (8, 'aaa');    
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Read more about it here from a previous question: [return the updated value after running the update query in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969684/return-the-updated-value-after-running-the-update-query-in-mysql)

It does, however, support `RETURNING` rows after an `INSERT` or `REPLACE` statement (if you're using version 10.5 and higher), like this:

```
INSERT INTO news (ID, title) values (8, 'aaa') RETURNING *;
```

```
REPLACE INTO news VALUES (8,'changed') RETURNING *;
```

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/9oTbNV9e).**

Read more about it in the MariaDB Documentation: [REPLACE...RETURNING](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replacereturning/).

Comment: An UPDATE statement doesn't affect LAST_`INSERT`_ID(), even if you update the id.

Comment: @GeorgRichter you are correct, thanks for pointing out my mistake. I've updated my answer. I actually never tried to retrieve it from an `UPDATE` statement, but I read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_last_insert_id.asp) that you can do it for an `UPDATE` statement; after trying it myself, its not the case (hence the phrase LAST_`INSERT`_ID). I guess you can't believe everything you read on the internet...